# Windows 10 Mobile - Family Safety Screen Time / Phone Calls & Text

Tags: windows-10-mobile, family-safety

Can you still make phone calls / text when Windows 10 Mobile family locks you out via Screen Time limits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this limit doesn't apply to mobile; only to PCs. There's no mention of it [here](https://account.microsoft.com/family/faq/), and if you go into the settings it says:

> Applies to Windows 10 PCs.

Again no mention of mobile.